# Logging out of all stackexchange sites with one click

Tags: feature-request, logout

Often I visit a number of stackexchange sites. There does not seem to be a way to log out of all of the sites with one click. IMHO this would be a nice feature. If there is such a feature I would appreciate learning how to use it.

Comment: iirc the logout button does exactly that, though you'd still have to log out from your OpenID provider if you use one.

Comment: I was just logged into this site, math.stackexchange, and my ID provider. I logged out of my ID provider and then out of this site. I was still logged into math.stackexchange.